# Remove text from line

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have a log file that I essentially cat the entire log out, cut it up strings until there are only two fields remaining, sort uniquely on field one and sum up field to the right when field numbers and field1 are the same.  Example

```
80 128 
443 40
80 100
25  20 
443 44
80 128
```

The results would be

```
80 356
443 84
25  20
```

The issue I am having is there is an inconsistency in the first field that I cut out where sometimes output will look like:

80 128

and sometimes it is

```
80(LOCAL\randomuser) 128
```

So my output ends up looking like

```
80 356
80(LOCAL\randomuser) 128
443 84
25  20
```

this is because 80(LOCAL\randomuser) is a unique line.

How can I first normalize the first field so that (LOCAL\randomuser) is removed from lines where exist while lines that do not have (LOCAL\randomuser) remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$NF} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' input
```

I.e use first field as key and add the last field.

If there isn't a space between the first number and the `(` as it looks like in your example, tell awk to split on `(` as well:

```
awk -F"[ (]+" '{a[$1]+=$NF} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' input
```

output:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$NF} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' input
25 20
80 356
443 84
```

Another approach to remove the just the `(LOCAL\randomuser)` if present, you can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/(.*)//' input
```

Comment: you could use -F'[^[:digit:]]+' and it'll work whether there's a space or not (or any other non-digits) after the first number.

Answer (score 1):

Or force `$1` into numerical context:

```
awk '{A[$1+0]+=$NF} END{for (i in A) print i, A[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -v` will match lines that **do not contain** a pattern. Pipe the output through `grep` before it reaches `cut`.

Comment: It seems that OP does not want to exclude any lines but rather to remove a specific sub-string from Column 1.

Comment: The problem is that I want the lines I just need to remove that text. If I match online lines that do not contain the pattern then I am missing valuable data. I simply want to remove (LOCAL\username) from lines that have it and lines that dont leave alone.